# REST Bidnings for service reference in TIBCO Business Studio

Tags: asp.net-web-api, tibco

I am using `AMX Service Bus 3.2`. and trying to expose my rest services (ASP.NET WebApi) through the TIBCO Active Matrix. Unfortunately I have not found any way to do this in TIBCO business studio. 
I found `TIBCO Active Matrix Binding Type for REST` but it is intended only for promoted services. It allows to expose SOAP services via REST interface but it is unable to invoke my REST services hosted on IIS.

As for now I see the only one way to implement that - Create addition SOAP service that will redirect HTTP request from Promoted service to my REST Service. But such solution is not very good SOA design.

Any help is appreciated.